# SPListItemCollection to Dictionary<string, SPListItem>

Tags: splistitem, splistitemcollection, dictionary

Rather than repeatedly query a SharePoint list for information I need, I wanted to create a dictionary from an `SPListItemCollection` (where the dictionary key is the "Title" value of each `SPListItem`, and the value is the `SPListItem` itself). I tried this:

```
SPListItemCollection documentCodesListItems = documentCodesList.GetItems(query);

Dictionary<string, SPListItem> dictionary = (from SPListItem i in documentCodesListItems select new { Key = i.Title, Value = (SPListItem)i }).ToDictionary(
                a => a.Key,
                a => a.Value);
```

But I get `"Value does not fall within the expected range."` exception. Can anybody see my mistake, or should I do this differently?

Comment: Your code works fine for me provided I use a unique field other than Title. Dictionary keys should be unique but Title can be the same for many items. Can you try using ID / Internal name?

Comment: Do you have any duplicate Title?

Comment: Thanks so much Akhoy and Atish. I figured out that I was (stupidly) forgetting to include the Title field as one of the SPQuery view fields!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce following error when my CAML query is wrong. So it's time to re-check your CAML query again.

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

Generating Dictionary from items is perfect. You have to consider following thing while generating Dictionary from items where `Title` is the `Key` of Dictionary.

> Keys can not be duplicate for Dictionary

Use [u2u caml builder](http://www.u2u.be/Software) for building CAML query

Comment: Oh thank you so much. It turns out my CAML was not wrong, but I wasn't including the Title as one of the view fields! Doh! I hadn't looked at other things before because I was so sure it was how I wrote the Linq. Thanks again!